# How to avoid duplicate pages with collections using jekyll paginate v2?

Tags: jekyll, paginator

I followed the approach to install paginate v2 and paginate a collection, but I get an additional "Example Collection" top level page link for every page created by paginator.

Here is example.md

```
---
layout: page
title: Example Collection
permalink: /example/
pagination: 
  enabled: true
---

{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}

{% if paginator.total_pages > 1 %}
<ul>
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl }}">Newer</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl }}">Older</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

And this is what I added to my config.yml

```
# Collections
collections:
  examplecol:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/

# Plugin: Pagination (jekyll-paginate-v2)
pagination:
  collection   :  'examplecol'
  enabled      : true
  debug        : false
  per_page     : 3
  #permalink    : "/page/:num/"
  title        : ":title - Page :num of :max"
  limit        : 0
  sort_field   : "date"
  sort_reverse : true
```

Now, if there are more than 3 files in the `_examplecol` folder, I get more than 1 instance of the example.md as a page in my header.

How can I have just one instance of Example Collection in the header that holds all of the paginated pages? I think I'm missing something silly.

I tried deleting the permalink entry in the example.md YAML, but that just made it so that the jekyll processor could not find examplecol/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a lot of trial and error, but I found the solution in the header.

When the paginator makes pages with some items, the site sees them as pages and renders them.

Therefore, the site finds all the true responses to my_page.title and creates page-links.

```
 <div class="trigger">
            {% for my_page in site.pages %}
              {% if my_page.title %}
              <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Since the paginator pages are autogen, you can filter them out:

```
<div class="trigger">
        {% for my_page in site.pages %}
          {% if my_page.title and my_page.autogen == nil %}
          <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```